# Python time of remote web server

Tags: python, time

In Python, I am trying to get the exact time of a remote server so that I can adjust the timing of a request.

I know that I can use this code to get a "ntp" time:

```
client = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = client.request('pool.ntp.org')
print( f"request packet sent LOCAL Client time: {datetime.fromtimestamp(response.orig_time, timezone.utc)}")
print( f"request packet received REMOTE Server time: {datetime.fromtimestamp(response.recv_time, timezone.utc)}")
```

Which returns very helpful information showing that my server is nearly 2 seconds ahead of the NTP server:

> request packet sent LOCAL Client time:      2023-02-17
> 18:14:46.008366+00:00
>
> request packet received REMOTE Server time: 2023-02-17
> 18:14:44.369423+00:00

Is there a way to get the time of a web server, rather than an NTP server?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the time of a web server, rather than an NTP
> server?

In most case you should be able to find `Date` in response headers, consider following simple example

```
import requests  # if you do not have it, install it: pip install requests
r = requests.head("http://www.example.com")  # ask just for headers
date_str = r.headers["Date"]  # retrieve Date value
print(date_str)  # e.g. Fri, 17 Feb 2023 18:43:06 GMT
```

If you need to parse date string you might use [`email.utils.parsedate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.parsedate) (part of standard library).

Comment: That works down to the second level.  Any way to get to Millisecond?  I don't see it in the header data.